# how to slice low-resolution pandas df (freq=1min) with higher resolution indexer (freq=1D)?

Tags: datetime, numpy, pandas

I would like to retain the '1min' resolution of data, and return a subset of the df where the date matches one of the three in the indexer

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range("2013-10-08 00:00:00","2015-10-08 00:00:00", freq="1min",tz='UTC'))
df['data']=np.random.random_integers(0,1,len(df))
indexer=["2013-12-24","2014-01-16","2015-02-19"]
```

The following doesn't work:

```
df.loc[pd.DatetimeIndex(indexer)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get integer location by function [get_loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) and then you can select data by [df.ix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html).

But you need not only midnight, but also [1440](https://www.unitjuggler.com/convert-time-from-day-to-min.html) minutes in one day.

I used list comprehension again with function [range](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) with range midnight from `00:00:00+00:00` to `23:59:00+00:00`. Last [flat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) list was created, because range returned lists of list.

```
print df.head()
#                           data
#2013-10-08 00:00:00+00:00     0
#2013-10-08 00:01:00+00:00     0
#2013-10-08 00:02:00+00:00     1
#2013-10-08 00:03:00+00:00     0
#2013-10-08 00:04:00+00:00     0

#list comprehension - get loc of dates
idx = [df.index.get_loc(pd.to_datetime(i)) for i in indexer]
print idx
#[110880, 144000, 718560]

#add 1439 + 1 minutes, because range is 0 indexing
idx = [range(i, i+1440) for i in idx]
#flatten list
idx = [y for x in idx for y in x]

#select df by integer indexes
df = df.ix[idx]

print df.head()
#                           data
#2013-12-24 00:00:00+00:00     1
#2013-12-24 00:01:00+00:00     0
#2013-12-24 00:02:00+00:00     0
#2013-12-24 00:03:00+00:00     0
#2013-12-24 00:04:00+00:00     1
print df.tail()
#                           data
#2015-02-19 23:55:00+00:00     1
#2015-02-19 23:56:00+00:00     0
#2015-02-19 23:57:00+00:00     0
#2015-02-19 23:58:00+00:00     0
#2015-02-19 23:59:00+00:00     0
```